# Confusing syntax of deque. What does this syntax mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, declaration, deque

I have a C++ code for `deque` which declares the `deque` and I do not understand what it means?

```
deque<int> pile[7];
```

The above deque used is from standard library implementation of C++
I did an extensive research on it but no body has used it this way. I don't know if this is

1. "deque of deques" or
2. "deque of arrays" or
3. "arrays of deque"

Kindly please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any type `T`, `T[N]` denotes an *array* of `N` elements of type `T`.

You have `T pile[7]` with `T = deque<int>`, so `pile` is an array of seven deques.